# Wifi connection problems ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, 15.04

I dual boot my macbook with osx and ubuntu 15.04, and I have had a persistent issue connecting to wifi in the latter. Whenever I wake my computer, the computer will remain unconnected to wifi. When I click the icon in the top right, it shows no wifi networks but has "enable wifi" checked. I have had to uncheck and check it again for it to connect. Any thoughts on what may be going wrong and how I may fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been around for quite some time and is considered a bug already.

There's a swift solution to this though:

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh

sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh

sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
```

Enter the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
thaw|resume)
nmcli nm sleep false
;;
*)
;;
esac
exit $?
Save
```

It's working now on my Dell XPS 15 9530 running Ubuntu 15.04 and Ubuntu 15.10. :)

(Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182128&p=12830153#post12830153)